# How are the req and res objects created in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, https, request, response

I understand what the req and res objects contain, what they are used for, and when they are created, but I was wondering how they are created.

Comment: The express source is on github!

Answer (score 0):

The req and res objects that you are referring to come from an npm package called [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express). Express is a lightweight package that allows you to handle HTTP requests on your node server.

Below is a small example of how to use the package with some example HTTP endpoints.

In the example, I also use a package called 'body-parser' this package is used to parse any HTTP requests with a JSON body. The package puts the parsed body into the req object at the key body, as can be seen in the code example.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Handle GET / request here
});
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // Handle POST / request here
  // Get body of request
  var body = req.body;
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Listening on port 8080'));
```

Comment: `req` and `res` are not created by express. They are created by the nodejs api and they are only extended by expressjs with additional features.

Answer (score 0):

req and res are the component of Express framework of Node package manager(npm) and is used to respond as per the request created by the user.

```js
//To print Date as string


const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-Parser");

const app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  var today = new Date();
  var options = {
    weekday: "long",
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
  };

  var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

  res.render("list", {
    kindOfDay: day
   
  });

});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var item = req.body.selectSection;
  items.push(item);
  res.redirect("/");

});

app.listen("3000", function() {
  console.log(" the server is runnimg in port 3000");
});
```